# How to pass a variable/change html from php

Tags: php

So I'm using PHP to grab my profile picture from my steam profile and i want to display it on the page is there any way to pass the variable containing the picture to html or edit my html code from PHP???

here is my code

```
<?php

$pic_path = file_get_contents("http://steamcommunity.com/id/LocalSugarDaddy");
preg_match('/<div class="playerAvatarAutoSizerInner"><img src="(.*)" \/><\/div>/i', $pic_path, $pic);

?>
```

Comment: You could simply `echo` the variable.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to use PHP variable containing image URL and want to use in html  tag. If so, then you can do below:

```
<?php
$your_picture_str = "http://www.domainname.com/picture_url.jpg";
?>

<div><img src="<?php echo $your_picture_str; ?>" width="100%" alt="" title="" /></div>
```